# Xubunt Live USB hangs checking Windows partition

Tags: boot, live-usb

My notebook's SSD is dead. I tried to use a Xubuntu Live USB to use it while I don't change the SSD. But when I use the option "Try Xubuntu without installing" in the boot menu, it starts loading but get stuck checking Windows partition on SSD. It says that "The file system was not safely closed on Windows" but when it tries to fix it get stuck on errors (that makes sense since the SSD is dead). Is it possible to prevent this check? Or the only option is to physically remove the SSD? I've already checked the BIOS setup and there is no way to disable SATA.

Thanks,

Comment: Try to stop it by pressing:  Control+C